# Auto-Remove the Chat Notification

Tags: feature-request, chat

Can we have it so the notifications in chat go away after a certain amount of time automatically? It's very annoying when you get several notifications a day.

I'll snag a screenshot as soon as I can, but the typical notification(s):

Screenshot example, but not limited to:

[image]

Comment: maybe be more clear on which notifications you are talking about.

Comment: added examples and a screenshot